# How can I download all media exchanged with a WhatsApp contact on web.whatsapp.com?

Tags: whatsapp, bulk-download

How can I download all media exchanged with a WhatsApp  contact on https://web.whatsapp.com?

Comment: By selecting the items one by one and then clicking on the download icon, that generates an archive with everything you selected. I couldn’t find a _select all_ option.